# How to put words from an input file into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, file

So I'm trying to separate the words from an input file and put them into an array. However, when I try to fit them into my array during a loop, I later try to print my array and it only returns NULL for each item. Here's what I got:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (void)
{
    FILE *inputfile;
    int table_size = 100;
    char *table[table_size];
    inputfile = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char str[60];
    char *token;
    int i = 0;
    if (inputfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file!");
        return 1;
    }


     while ( fgets (str, 60, inputfile)!=NULL )
     {
        token = strtok(str, " ");

        while (token != NULL)
        {
           token = table[i];
           //strcpy(table[i], token);
           i++;
           token = strtok(NULL, " ");
         }
      }

    int x;
    for (x=0; x <= sizeof(table)/sizeof(int); x++)
        {
         printf("%s \n", table[x]);
        }
    fclose(inputfile);

return 2;

}
```

I know the while loop separates the file into words, but for some reason I can't manage to get those words into the array properly. I have a commented out strcpy function in there because I feel like that function could help a lot, but it isn't working properly either when I try to implement it.

I'm not sure if the problem is with memory allocation or what. I'm a beginner and transitioning from python to C, so I'm not used to memory allocation, pointers, and the like. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `table[i] = strdup(token);`

Comment: `for (x=0; x <= sizeof(table)/sizeof(int); x++)` --> `for (x=0; x < i; x++)`

Comment: Both comments as small as they were, helped immensely. Thanks guys.

Comment: the posted code does not compile cleanly.  this line: `for (x=0; x <= sizeof(table)/sizeof(int); x++)` raises a warning about comparison between signed and unsigned values.   To fix that, remember that `sizeof` returns a `size_t`, which is unsigned, so the variable `x` should also be unsigned.  suggest defining `x` as: `size_t x;` rather than `int x;`

Comment: what is this line: `token = table[i];` expected to be doing?  Perhaps you meant: `table[i] = strdup( token );`

Comment: the posted code contains several `magic` numbers.  `magic` numbers make the code much more difficult to understand and are a real headache when debugging or performing maintenance.  Suggest using #defines' or an enum to give the `magic` number meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: these two lines: `int table_size = 100;
    char *table[table_size];` clearly define the number of entries available in the table[] array,  so why is the value `100` being re-calculated with: `for (x=0; x <= sizeof(table)/sizeof(int); x++)`  rather than: `for (x=0; x <= table_size; x++)`?   Note: the variable `table_size` is a very good candidate for a #define and eliminate that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you have a two-dimensional array with an unknown amount of elements in table. You can use `strdup` to dynamically allocate memory for the element.

```
while (fgets (str, 60, inputfile)!=NULL) {
  token = strtok(str, " ");

  while (token != NULL)
  {
     table[i] = strdup(token);
     i++;
     token = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
}
```

Also your code for printing the elements is not correct because `sizeof` can't determine the amount of elements in a dynamically allocated block of memory. Instead you can iterate from 0 to i (which will be the size of table)

```
int x;
for (x=0; x < i; x++)
{
  printf("%s \n", table[x]);
  free(input[x]);
}
```

Because of the fact `strdup` allocates memory you need to free it when you're done (after your call to `printf`).

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @TheNavesinkBanks No problem, this was just to clearify what EOF and Cool Guy mentioned in the comments :)